# sql server net_address

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis

I have 2 applications in IIS which are calling same database. When I am executing the stored procedure which has below query, it returns 2  net_addresses every time.

These two address.

> Application 1 has net_address 001914828D7EEE
>
> Application 2 has net_address 0038B4A5DEC333

My question is why net_addresses are not same although those application are on same machine :)

P.S: Database is on other server.

```
SELECT  hostname,
        net_library,
        net_address,
        client_net_address
FROM    sys.sysprocesses AS S
INNER JOIN    sys.dm_exec_connections AS decc ON S.spid = decc.session_id
WHERE   spid = @@SPID
```

Output:

```
hostname | net_library | net_address | client_net_address
PIERRE   | TCP/IP      | 0090F5E5DEFF| 10.38.168.5
```

Comment: msdn states this `Assigned unique identifier for the network adapter on the workstation of each user. When a user logs in, this identifier is inserted in the net_address column.`

Comment: Maybe your apps are using different network adapters on the same machine?

Comment: they are using same network adapters :(

Answer (score 0):

1. If the net_Address starts with 00 the program which opened the connection is running in a simple environment or is a regular connection. If you have letter is because the connection was opened from SQl Analyzer or a server which shared sessions. Like using Terminal server or Remote desktop connection.

000EA61DBEFF MICHELENEW

B7D36284FF31 MICHELENEW

The "good" MAC address is 00-0E-...

2. How to map back the net_Address (MAC) to IP.
   In any domain controller from the DOS command type:

ARP -a

look for your MAC address in the list. I know this is a pain but the point is that U can get the info from DHCP. Maybe a script could help. Remembert ARP is a cache list but it helps.

3. From SQL Server type
   select net_address,loginame,hostname nt_username, * from master..sysprocesses order by net_address
   It can help you to figure it our who is using the connection.

[Source of answer](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/33ea48f3-5e40-48ca-875d-254a61af5f39/netaddress-in-the-masterdbosysprocesses-table?forum=transactsql)